# After applying the texture form UVimage editor, the model looks extremely dark and blue

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

Good afternoon, I did not know where to open the topic, I hope not to disturb
I do not know what happened but the model after applying the UVimage editor the model looks extremely dark and of a blue hue, being that the texture should be applied to itself, once it worked, but I do not know what happened but since that time already He did not succeed.
PS: apparently the texture was applied, but very dark and of that blue tone.

I leave photos thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: try to delete the light sources

Comment: Try a different viewport mode. Switch to Solid instead of Material. Then enable 'Texture Solids' in Display section of 3D Properties panel. (N-Key in 3D view.)

Comment: @dval great, thank you very much, now the model presents the texture :) I am very grateful.